# How to hide or replace <dl> html tag from WooCommerce related template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I've been researching how to remove/replace `<dl>` html tags from my Woocommerce web site for a long time, like:

```
<dl class = "Variation"> Starts: July 17, 2020 </dl>
```

I would just like to have instead (without html `<dl>` tags):

**Starts: July 17, 2020**

I have a function that redirects me to WhatsApp with the items in my cart. Everything is going well, except for this blessed `<dl>` tag that is displayed on WhatsApp message.

is there a way to hide it / remove it?

I'm doing this within `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php`

My code sends a message to Whatsapp listing the products, however I would like to hide this htlm tag `<dl class… >` of the message that is sent to whatsapp.

```
$Produtos .= "*".$item->get_quantity()."x* ".$item->get_name()."%0a%0a";
    $Produtos .= "*".$item->get_quantity()."x* ".$item->get_name()."%0a%0a - "  .wc_display_item_meta( $item, 'echo' );


I have little knowledge in php, please help me.
```

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, and then edit your question accordingly. Currently half the HTML you are talking about is not even visible.

Comment: _"except for this blessed <class dl"_ - I have _no idea_ what that is, where you see it, what it does or why or when it happens. We don't know your code. You need to give us some proper info here.

Comment: Hey, Edited @LoicTheAztec

Comment: As a new user, you should take the [quick tour (1 mn)](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how StackOverFlow works basically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes in a WooCommerce template file.

First read: [How to override WooCommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), to understand how you can make changes to some template files via your theme.

Now the templates you need to edit where `<dl class ="Variation">` is located is:

- [`cart/cart-item-data.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php)

Now you should be able to copy the template from woocommerce plugin to your active child theme (or active theme) folder on a **`woocommerce`** *folder* > **`cart`** *subfolder* > `cart-item-data.php` *file*

You need to respect the path (folder and subfolders hierarchy):

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart item data (when outputting non-flat)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-item-data.php.
 *
```

Then open / edit the freshly copied template file: 
You should able to change the html structure for `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dt>` html tags the desired ones *(you could replace them by `<ul>` `<li>` tags, making some changes to your CSS related styles)*.

So basically you can replace `(from line 20 to 26)`:

```
?>
<dl class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
        <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

with the following:

```
?>
<ul class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <li class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php 
             echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ). ': ';
             echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); 
        ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It should work… You will need to make some changes to your CSS related styles.

Comment: Hi, I made the changes you mentioned but it doesn't work = (

try doing a test on my website http://chamanozapdelivery.com/index.php/produto/corte-cabelo-maquina/

Comment: @MageGamer You have done something wrong in the process… but I am not going to teach you how to override properly templates files in WooCommerce as there is ton's of documentation on it. The only template file that I know that has `<dl>` tags is `cart/cart-item-data.php`, that displays variations attributes details on cart and checkout pages.

Comment: is there any way to (hide) this HTML code using strip_tags inside my 'echo'? When I tried to use it it hid the HTML, but it also hid the result in PHP (name of the variation) I would like it to hide only the html
 @LoicTheAztec